# "redirect_uri_mismatch" when sending authentication code to GoogleAPI

Tags: javascript, rest, google-api, google-oauth, restdb

I am having trouble with the authentication process for the GoogleAPI. In the end I want to be able to read the users steps using the GoogleFit API and then store that value in a database. Currently I'm using [restdb.io](https://restdb.io) and executing javascript in codehooks.

The documentation from Google that I am following can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3), clicking on the **HTTP/REST** option in the code examples. At the moment I am at step 5: I have gotten the users authentication code and stored it in the database. Now I have to POST the code along with some other parameters and get the access and refresh tokens.

If the POST is successful (from what I understand) I should get back a 200-OK message that the request was valid. Google will then POST a JSON body with the access and refresh token to the *redirect_uri* that I have specified in my GoogleAPI credentials page and the initial request. At *redirect_uri* I have to handle the request and save the two values.

The problem is that I receive a **redirect_uri_mismatch - Bad Request** message from Google as a response when executing the request. I get it at the `log.debug("ERROR HERE: " + [...]);` in the code below:

```
async function mainFunction(){

    const authCode = THIS_IS_MY_AUTHENTICATION_CODE;

    try {
        var answer = await postRequestToGoogle(authCode);
        //do stuff with response from Google
    } catch (error) {
        //do stuff
    }

}


async function postRequestToGoogle(authCode){
    
    //body for the request
    const params = "code=" + authCode + "&" +
    "client_id=THIS_IS_MY_CLIENT_ID" + "&" +
    "client_secret=THIS_IS_MY_CLIENT_SECRET" + "&" +
    "redirect_uri=THIS_IS_MY_REDIRECT_URI" + "&" +
    "grant_type=authorization_code";
    
    try{
        const result = await fetch('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
            body: params})
        .then(res => {
            log.debug("ERROR HERE: " + JSON.stringify(res.json()));
            return res.json();
        })
        //return JSON back main function
        return result;
    }catch(error){
        //do stuff      
    }
}
```

I looked up the error message and tried some things:

- Copy and pasted multiple different *Authorized redirect URI* from the GoogleAPI credentials page into the code to make sure that there is no problem with

  - http/https
  - www/no www
  - trailing slashes
  - typos or capitalization
- Waited for changes to be processed by Google (read that it can more than 30min)
- Changed all the other parameters to see if the *redirect_uri* is actually the problem

  - If *code* is changed the message is **invalid_grant - Bad Request**
  - If *client_id* is changed the message is **invalid_client - The OAuth client was not found**
  - If *client_secret* is changed the message is **invalid_client - Unauthorized**
  - If the *grant_type* is changed the message is **unsupported_grant_type - Invalid grant_type**

That's why I think the issue is the *redirect_uri*, but it's unclear to me how since I copy&pasted it. Something that came to mind was that maybe the value of *redirect_uri* gets changed when it's read by Google? Or maybe when the request is being put together? Do some characters have to be replaced?

I tried to analyze the request with Wireshark but didn't think about the fact that it's HTTPS so I would have I would have to decrypt it.. Is that something I should look into?

Thank you for taking the time to read all of this! If you have any advice please let me know :)

---

Update 16.11.20:

I have created a new *OAuth 2.0 Client ID* and used the new id/secret in my request. The resulting message the same as before. I will wait and try again tomorrow to see if maybe Google needs some more time. Then I'll try to delete all current IDs and start with a fresh GoogleAPI project.

---

Update 19.11.20:

Creating a new *OAuth 2.0 Client ID* did not resolve my problem, neither did creating a whole new GoogleAPI project and adding those credentials into the request. I am in contact with the developers of [restdb.io](https://restdb.io) and have asked them to add the [Google Auth Library: Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs) to the list of supported Node.js packages. Hopefully that will help, I will give it a try as soon as it can be used :)

---

Update 02.12.20:

No progress so far, but I'm optimistic that the developers will add the package soon. I will post a final update as soon as I am done with this project.

Comment: Have you checked if the [google api js client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) supports google fit? If it does it would defiantly save you a lot of pain.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I just checked and it is supported. I want to access the users data without him being in front of the computer, so I would have to refresh the token every 45min.. That sounds like it's not very "clean" but I will check it out for sure.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support refresh tokens that would be a security risk.  You need to use a server sided language if you want a refresh token.

Comment: I meant "to refresh the auth token", as mentioned in the [js client FAQs].(https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/faq.md). How bad of an idea is it to save the auth token in a DB table and write a function that auto-refreshes all tokens in the table?

Comment: JavaScript is client side for a refresh token to work you would need to include the refresh token and the client id into your code which i could view source on and then instantly have access to a users data.  How is that not a bad idea?